# How to filter thymeleaf list with angular

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add on my thymeleaf based site and want to add user input based to filter the given list. I tried quite a few ways but I'm hitting a wall so if anyone can show me how to pass data to Angular it would be awesome.

This is the list/table in thymeleaf:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Characteristics</th>
            <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="2">Administration Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <th:block th:each="item, iterStat : ${list}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${iterStat.count}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.manufacturer.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.type}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.characteristics}"></td>
                <td class="text-center" th:text="${item.quantity}"></td>
                <td class="text-center"><a th:href="@{${'fuses/' + item.id}}"
                    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                </a> <a th:href="@{${'fuses/' + item.id + '/delete'}}"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
                </a></td>

            </tr>
        </th:block>
</table>
```

I'm not sure is there any more data needed, this is the mock search paragraph that I used:

```
<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test">
</p>
```

I want to filter the list by manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

First, thymeleaf is a templating engine that provides you server side generated html. AngularJS is client side. Once you're using thymemeaf rendering, you lost the ability to use angular databinding. And you've to do some dirty JS to get this functionality.

If you want to get angular filter on your webapp, you have to :

- Pass data to angular. So you've to use REST services that provides you a JSON data. For this, you've to change your backend code; you should not return a String or ModelAndView but @ResponseBody.
- Once you got this, you include AngularJS by defining a Controller that holds in its scope a reference to your JSON data provided by your server.
- Notice that your JSON data must be gathered through a service for XHR (Angular 1.x $http || $resource, for AngularJS ~ 4 HttpClient). This service must be injected into your controller as a dependency.

Your view code will look like :

```
<div  ng-controller="YouAngularController">
    <p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="test">
    </p>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Characteristics</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter : test">
            <td th:text="{{::item.id}}"></td>
            <td th:text="{{::item.manufacturer.name}}"></td>
            <td th:text="{{::item.type}}"></td>
            <td th:text="{{::item.characteristics}}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Notice that test is the object in your scope, binded by ng-model

For the AngularJS Controller :

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('YourAngularDeclaredModule').controller('YourAngularController', ['$scope','YourFactory',function($scope, YourFactory){
        $scope.items = [];
        YourFactory.fetchAll().then(function(xhrData){
            $scope.items = xhrData.data;
        }
        }).catch(function(data){
            console.log('error');
        });
    }]);
})();
```

You can see these links for example : 
https://github.com/meyacine/angular-restapi-tutorial

If it's with a great impact for your architecture, to change to REST. I recommand you to use jQuery DataTables to get the asked feature.

Good Luck :)